# GET http://localhost:8080/main.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on deploying on Netlify console error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, netlify

[image]

The static website got published but was blank. Throwing the following error:

Answer (score 0):

The webpack.config.js file has a publicpath object which specifies the base path of all your assets. It is set by default as

```
output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:8080/main.js" ,
  },
```

Make it as

```
output: {
publicPath: 'auto',
```

},

Answer (score 0):

in webpack config:

```
output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    // whatever path folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
  },
```

In netlify, you have publish directory property. Since I output to "dist"

[image]